# Submit HTML in WKWebView

Tags: swift

In Javascript you can build HTML and use $(formElement).submit() to submit your HTML in a browser. I'm trying to do the same in Swift but get a blank screen. I'm not trying to display the HTML but submit it in the WKWebView.

```
var finalHTML = “<form method='POST' action='https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans'><input type='hidden' name='PAY_REQUEST_ID' value='DC917AF1-C2A6-AEDA-2412-2F355752989C'></input><input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUM' value='1F69DF2D455FAAE2797F5F44FA7BEB05'></input></form>”

webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "message")
self.webView.loadHTMLString(finalHTML, baseURL: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added the following to your original code (after your corrections):

- `<html>` + `<body>` tags
- `onload` with JavaScript to trigger the submit of the form right after the page loads
- the `onload` contains a `setTimeout()` wrapping the code that triggers the submit, usually is not needed, but I've added it for extra safety
- remove the `userContentController`, I don't think it is needed (unless there's something else going on after the form is submitted)

Try the updated code:

```
var finalHTML = "<html><body onload='setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector('form').submit() }, 1)'><form method='POST' action='https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/process.trans'><input type='hidden' name='PAY_REQUEST_ID' value='DC917AF1-C2A6-AEDA-2412-2F355752989C'></input><input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUM' value='1F69DF2D455FAAE2797F5F44FA7BEB05'></input></form></body></html>"

webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
self.webView.loadHTMLString(finalHTML, baseURL: nil)
```